# Вывод постов из категорий

Tags: python, django

Ни как не могу вывести посты по категориям.

**models**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField('Транслит', max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Category')
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField('Транслит', max_length=200, db_index=True, )
    description = models.TextField('Описание', blank=True, )
    text = models.TextField('Текст поста', )
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField('Опубликовать?', default=True, )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**vievs**

```
def post_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        posts = posts.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'post/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'posts': posts})
```

В *post/list.html* на выходе получается отобразить только название категории. а вот пост не выводит вообще никак.  Подскажите в каком направлении капать?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, Ваш шаблон. Вы можете добавить его, нажав кнопку [edit]. Вроде, посты передаются в контекст, поэтому проблем с выводом не должно быть.

Comment: Шаблон сейчас пустой уже. Сижу думаю над проблемой...

Comment: Скорее, всего, ошибка была у Вас в шаблоне. Попробуйте написать в нём `{% for post in posts %}{{ post.text }}{% endfor %}` и посмотреть, что выведется.

Comment: Пустой экран выведет. и все что связано с {{ post.*** }} выдает пустой экран

Comment: Все разобрался. забыл просто в админке "available" выставить.